# IntelliJ IDEA plugin not getting downloaded

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to download Sequence Diagram plugin in Intellij IDEA. But it is not succeeding. It is failing without giving any error!!! What could be the reason?
I tried all three plugins SequenceDiagram, SequencePlugin and SequencePluginReloaded. For all three, it behaves the same.

[image]

I have set proxy as below. Without proxy, it was not listing any plugin when I entered "sequence" in search box.

[image]

Comment: Are you using a web proxy? Have you set it up in IJ ?

Comment: Yes I have set the proxy. Without proxy, it was not listing any plugin when I entered "sequence" in search box.

Comment: @Mahesha999 should be a one of connectivity issues. Can't you download the zip from here https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6134?pr= and try 'install plugin from disk' ??

Comment: I tried that several times...it always failed until this time :) I love this plugin now, none on eclipse work so smooth...Btw just guessing why it did not worked earlier...

Comment: Just try the direct link... https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6134?pr=idea

Comment: I was saying it worked finally by installation from disk. But it failed all times earlier I tried. Also was guessing what is "COMPATIBLE BUILDS" column in that table? Max number there is `139.1117`. And my IntelliJ says `162.1121.32`